# Why do I get Call to undefined function updatedb()

Tags: 7, drush

I am attempting to wrap my head around some of the advance features of drush.  i am using **Drush User's Guide** and it's example code and ran into this error [`Fatal error: Call to undefined function updatedb() in /home/trakz/.drush/user_blocker.drush.inc on line 68`]from the code below.

**Line 68** is: [`$query= updatedb('users')`]

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?  I have checked the Drush guide and updatedb() is valid.  Googling around did not help.

drupal 6.28
drush 5.7

**any assistance woudl be greatly appreciated.**  Thank you.

```
/**
 * Callback implementation for user-blocker command
 */
function drush_user_blocker() {
  // Grab all languages given. If any.
  $languages = func_get_args();

  // See if we received a date from which we should filter
  $since = strtotime(drush_get_option('since', '2 years ago')); 

  // Perform the update over the users table
  $query= updatedb('users')
  ->fields(array('status' => 0,))
  ->condition('uid', array(0, 1), 'NOT IN')
  ->condition('access', array(1, $since), 'BETWEEN');

  // Add the condition to filter by language
  if (count($languages)) {
    $query->condition('language', $languages, 'IN');
  } 

  $total_blocked = $query->execute();
  drush_log(dt("Blocked !total_blocked users", array('!total_blocked' => $total_blocked)), 'success');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drush updatedb` is a valid command.

`updatedb (updb)       Apply any database updates required (as with running update.php).`

However, I'm not sure about using it in place of `db_query`.

In D7 you would use `db_update` there.

In D6, you're stuck with `db_query`

It looks like a syntax error in the module code, it probably needs to use D6 style `db_query`

Comment: HI David.  I added the d6 style and at least got past the line, now I get an error on the next line [->fields(array('status' => 0,))] member function field is a non-object.  Think I had better find another tutorial to use.  Thank you for your help.